# Server 2008-R2 batch file not moving files with correct IUSR permission

Tags: php, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I have a batch file that moves copies files from a temp directory to a public directory on server 2008 R2.  The folder is readable by the server, but the file that the gets copied doesn't have the correct IUSR permissions.  Is there a way to auto set permissions for any files that gets copies into the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.  I added IUSR permissions to the windows/temp directory and it is inheriting the right permissions now.